# Is this specific question edit legit?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197629/frequency-vs-time-graph-in-processing) looks like this:

> I'd like to make a frequency vs. Time graph for an mp3 file that ill input using the minim library so that I can pick maximum frequencies and low frequencies and perform operations on said graph...any help?

So anyway it's a bad question. However, in [its revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28197629/revisions), we can see <del>a pretty bad edit from a 10k user</del> that in the fourth revision the question was reworked from scratch.
It was about some Android Java thingy and is now about a broad time graph.
The question does not have any answer (that I can see as a <10k user).

Is this kind of edit legit? What should happen now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Absolutely not.***

Even though the OP made that edit, it completely changed the question. The OP should've asked a new question, instead.