# Should we stop the [creation] of new questions with this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I propose the burnination of the [creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/creation) tag. While it means creating something, that isn’t really specific enough to be useful as a tag. Note that we do need to follow the official burnination process, and anyone trying to circumvent it may get suspended by a moderator.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. It refers to creating something, but a more specific tag would be a preferred choice. The tag info literally states "Do not use. Too vague to be of any possible significance.", with the wiki adding that the tag should be removed.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Depending on what is being created, but that does not excuse a poor tag.

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

Nope.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Also, no.

So, should we remove the tag?

Comment: We could remove it... but since there's nothing to prevent it from being re-created, and it inevitably will be, there's little point. Basically, burnination is a waste of time.

Comment: @IanKemp, aren't burninations usually end up in adding burned tag into block list? Or you mean something else?

Comment: No, burnination does not include blocking tags, the reason being that tag blocking is a manual process that cannot be performed by the community; it has to be escalated to Stack Exchange staff.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that it will be inevitably recreated.  481 (non-deleted; there are an additional 290 deleted) questions in 14 years is really not *that* many given that it's been freely usable the entire time.  Removing it is a significant barrier to its use, and it could be re-removed and blocklisted fairly easily if it came back given the relatively slow pace of new questions with it.

Comment: If you think creation is pointless, a tag search for "create" unearths many more very useful looking tags :) People just like to create stuff.

Comment: I blame the God Complex.

Comment: Agreed - "creation" means nothing without context. Looking at the questions that are tagged, they are all over the place.

Comment: @Fattie Ugh. No. There is a [clear process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070) for this, which includes the proposal (eventually) being featured. It has been made abundantly clear that encouraging users to "just burninate tags" is not acceptable. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418374) (context: user wanted to ignore process for tag burnination) (and the comments, but specifically Cody Gray's answers). Users that suggest that we blatantly ignore the process may have moderator action taken against them.

Comment: @cocomac I see, it's good to know there's a process. Is there any way to help that process along??